# Relationship among window, rootviewcontroller, childviewcontroller, navigationcontroller in iOS

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I haven't really seen any resource that gives a good and simple explanations on relationship among window, rootviewcontroller, childviewcontroller, navigationcontroller and how they piece together in iOS development. Anyone one knows how to put this in a easy-to-understand way or any online resource or book that does a good job in explaining it?

Comment: Have you read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)?

Comment: Can you mention at least two or three resources you went through before concluding there are no good explanations in that regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation on UIWindow:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/

> A UIWindow object provides the backdrop for your app’s user interface and provides important event-handling behaviors. Windows do not have any visual appearance of their own, but they are crucial to the presentation of your app’s views.

Xcode typically provides your application's main window, but you can add more if you need to.

From the documentation link you can see that `UIWindow` is actually a `UIView`

Enter your first view controller. Like providing a main window, when you start a new Project in Xcode the project template usually wires up your initial view controller, which as the name implies controls a view (UIView).

You could call this initial view controller your *RootViewController* but if you get a handle on the UIWindow you could just as easily swap out the current initial view controller's view for any other view controller view you like.

That probably doesn't help with hard and fast rules for things, but if I understand what you are asking, *RootViewController* is likely the initial view controller for you application. For example, if you are using Storyboards, Xcode typically makes `Main.storyboard`, you will see a gray arrow pointing to the UIViewController representation.

[image: gray arrow]

This is pointing to the Storyboards Initial View Controller. You can verify this from the Attributes Inspector. Select the view controller then select the attribute inspector:

[image: initial view controller]

So that's basically *RootViewController*. *ChildViewController* is just any other view controller that is a child of a view controller.

I assume what you are referring to is:

```
addChildViewController:

removeFromParentViewController

willMoveToParentViewController:

didMoveToParentViewController:
```

You can read more about these methods here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/

Under **Implementing a Container View Controller**

The quick gist of it is, A View Controller controls a view. View's can have subviews. Those subviews can come from other View Controllers. The methods outlined above pretty much just enable things like `viewWillAppear`, or `viewWillDiappear` to be called on the child view controller automatically when those methods are invoked on the parent view controller.

Per the docs:

> By default, rotation and appearance callbacks are automatically forwarded to children. You may optionally override the `shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` and `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` methods to take control of this behavior yourself.

a *NavigationController* is just like any other View Controller. It contains some special behavior for transitioning between views, but like other View Controllers it has a View (UIView) that it manages. A navigation controller could be your Initial View Controller / *RootViewController* just as any other View Controller can be, it all just depends on what you are trying to do. For example, a simple app that is just a list view, where you can tap an item and get a detail view could be constructed as:

1) Initial View Controller -> NavigationController

2) The NavigationController's first ViewController (Apple calls this a RootViewController) would then be a TableViewController.

3) Selecting a TableCell in the TableView (TableViewController manages a TableView) would then transition you to your Detail View Controller. The Navigation Controller knows how to do all that Sliding back and forth drama.

That's a pretty simplistic overview you can search the internet/youtube for more full featured tutorials outlining the same thing in more detail.

Example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1

It's worth your time to do a few of these to get your bearings. Yes, it will likely cost you a few hours of your day. Take heart, everyone who ever started doing iOS development had to go though the same thing. =)